# Pass string literal to the function argument which constructor only takes std::string_view

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17, string-literals, string-view

Suppose I have an object only has `std::string_view` constructor:

```
struct OnlyStringViewCtor {
  std::string str_;
  OnlyStringViewCtor(std::string_view str) : str_(str) {}
};
```

and there is a function that takes `const OnlyStringViewCtor&` as parameter:

```
void f(const OnlyStringViewCtor&) {}
```

when I call `f("hello")` directly there is a compiler error:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const OnlyStringViewCtor&' from expression of type 'const char [6]'
```

Is there some nice way that can let `f("hello")` work fine and not declare another constructor such as `OnlyStringViewCtor(const char*)`?

Comment: Does `f("hello"sv)` work for you?

Comment: you could define an overload of `f` that accepts string_view. or call `f(MyClass{"test"})`... maybe even `f({"test"})` ?

Comment: @Dmitry Kuzminov, works for me, but I just curious there some way that not specify `sv`.

Comment: @Patrick Parker. `f({"test"})` is a nice way, never thought about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answer explained, the compiler won't do multiple implicit conversions.

But, you can use a template to bridge the gap:

```cpp
struct OnlyStringViewCtor {
  std::string str_;
  template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<std::string, T>, int> = 0>
  OnlyStringViewCtor(T str) : str_(str) {}
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1reajv

Comment: Using template  seems to be the good alternative. And adopt C++20 concepts such as `OnlyStringViewCtor(std::convertible_to<std::string_view> auto const& string_like)` would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

The call `f("hello");` is not possible. This would need an implicit conversion from `char const [6]` to `std::string_view`, and then one more implicit conversion to `OnlyStringViewCtor`, but only one implicit conversion is allowed for a function argument.

A simple fix would be to call `f` with a `string_view` literal, like this:

```
using namespace std::literals;
f("hello"sv);
```

Comment: The namespace should be std::string_view_literals

Answer (score -1):

Second answer on this post was good, but the namespace could be corrected:

```
using namespace std::string_view_literals;
f("hello"sv);
```